# Background sync not firing event in serviceworker

Tags: javascript, synchronization, service-worker, offline-caching, service-worker-events

My sync event not firing, am using **chrome webserver** to serve a page on my desktop PC on **localhost:5000** and using a fetch api to POST data to the local development server on a separate port **localhost:1337**. Have turned off my wifi, the chrome webserver and also the offline toggle in the chrome devtool, yet still not firing my event.

**This is my code in serviceworker.js snippet for sync**

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {   
  if (event.tag == 'syncrhronizeOfflineData') 
  {     
    event.waitUntil(syncrhronizeData());   
  } 
}); 
async function syncrhronizeData() {   
  console.log('now synchronizing data...');   
  //first get all favourites in the localDB and post them to server 
  const favData = await window.localforage.getItem('restaurants')
    .filter((r) => r.isoffline );   
  console.log('favdata', favData); 
}
```

Have not actually posted to the database yet, trying to console **favdata** but not getting the message, the event is not been triggered.

**Snippet in main.js where i register serviceworker**

```
/**  * Service worker functions below  */ 
registerServiceWorker = () => {    
if (!navigator.serviceWorker) return;    
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
.then((reg) => {     
  if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) return;     
  if (reg.waiting) {        
    updateWorker(reg.waiting);       
    return;     
  }      
  if (reg.installing) {         
    trackInstalling(reg.installing);       
    return;     
  }      
  reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {      
    trackInstalling(reg.installing);     
  });    
}).catch(function(err) {      
  console.error(err); // the Service Worker didn't install correctly   
});    
//background sync for favourites and reviews offline posting   
if ('SyncManager' in window || 'sync' in reg) {   
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(swRegistration) { 
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] is ready - sync is registered');        
    return swRegistration.sync.register('syncrhronizeOfflineData');     
 });   
}     
};
```

Am getting a console message that '**[ServiceWorker] is ready - sync is registered**' but not getting a message from the sync event after i posted data offline and reconnect back.

Answer (score 0):

window object is not available inside ServiceWorker